# Java regex does not remove dots

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove ". ." in text, and replace it with ".".

My code:

```
System.out.println(TextHandler.class.toString() + " removeExcessiveSpaces E2 " + text);
while (text.contains("\\. \\.")) {
    text = text.replaceAll("\\. \\.", ".");
}
System.out.println(TextHandler.class.toString() + " removeExcessiveSpaces E3 " + text);
```

text input:

```
"from the streets' fit but you know it. . this is just another case of female stopping play,. in an otherwise total result of a holiday. by m-uhjuly 04, 2006. . 8 . 42 . .. .... . . . . . . . . <script>//<![cdata["
```

Expected output:

```
"from the streets' fit but you know it this is just another case of female stopping play,. in an otherwise total result of a holiday. by m-uhjuly 04, 2006. . 8 . 42 .. <script>//<![cdata["
```

Observed output:

```
from the streets' fit but you know it. . this is just another case of female stopping play,. in an otherwise total result of a holiday. by m-uhjuly 04, 2006. . 8 . 42 . .. .... . . . . . . . . <script>//<![cdata[
```

(no difference from input)

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String#contains` doesn't expect a regex just plain string.

so use:

```
if (text.contains(". .")) {
    text = text.replaceAll("\\. \\.", ".");
}
```

Or simply use `String#replace`:

```
text = text.replace(". .", ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
text = text.replace(". .", ".");
```

I expect it will helps to you!

Comment: I think you meant the `text.replace()`

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "from the streets' fit but you know it. . this is just another case of female stopping play,. in an otherwise total result of a holiday. by m-uhjuly 04, 2006. . 8 . 42 . .. .... . . . . . . . . <script>//<![cdata[";
        while (text.contains(". .")) {
            text = text.replaceAll("\\. \\.", ".");
        }
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

**Output**

```
from the streets' fit but you know it. this is just another case of female stopping play,. in an otherwise total result of a holiday. by m-uhjuly 04, 2006. 8 . 42 ..... <script>//<![cdata[
```

Answer (score 0):

`contains` doesn't use regex so instead of `contains("\\. \\.")` you should use `contains(". .")`.

But to replace series of `. . . . .` with one `.` instead of inefficient

```
while (text.contains(". .")) {
    text = text.replaceAll("\\. \\.", ".");
}
```

because in each iteration it needs to start from beginning of the string, you can use

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\.( \\.)+", ".");
```